# VS2010 asp.net: executing parameter less stored proc to update record

Tags: asp.net

I would like to execute a stored proc that simply updates a record. At this point I would like to keep it parameter less. But in future, I will be adding parameters to the stored proc. Can I simply do it via SQLDataSource? It will save me writing few lines of code to execute stored proc in a traditional ado.net. If its possible, could you please supply me with a sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`

Something like this...

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("p_UpdateSomething",  connectionstring);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or using a SqlDataSource like

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="sqlDS" runat="server" UpdateCommand="pUpdateSomething" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Update parameters can be added to the SqlDataSource.

Comment: How do I invoke sqlDS from the code behind such that updatecommand gets executed?

Comment: What web control is bound to your SQLDataSource?

Comment: There is no control bound to SQLDataSource. That is my question. I just want to execute stored proc via SQLDataSrouce. Is it possible????

Comment: So suppose you have a button, you could call the SQLDataSource.Update() method on the click event.

Comment: Got it.. I will give it a try and get back to you if this is still an issue. Thanks for your help.